# RAID 0 - what happens if mainboard changes?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, raid

I had an MSI z77a-g41 mainboard with Ocz vertex3 raid 0 configuration. Yesterday, my mainboard stopped booting.  It seems something is wrong with the mainboard because there is no video, no BIOS sounds, no messages are displayed, and keyboard illumination doesn't light up (g105 keyboard).
Now I found another used mainboard (Asus P8Z77-V PRO).

My question is, will my raid disks work on the new mainboard without any formatting? (I have some important files on my raid disks.)

I'm hoping my expectation is correct that they should work on the new mainboard because I think there is no special hardware raid controller on these mainboards and they have the same chipsets.

Comment: Wouldn't bet on it – it's "FakeRAID", not proper OS-level RAID, so it might still get quite confused by hardware changes... (That said, dm-raid on a Linux system will likely be able to understand the FakeRAID setup.)

Comment: With all the stuff that didn't work on the original, I'd look at the PSU before replacing the mainboard.

Answer (score 0):

RAID information for RAID arrays made with on-board desktop MB controllers is kept in the HDDs themselves, so the answer is **YES, the RAID will be detected** on another MB, given some conditions are met: RAID mode is enabled in the BIOS, boot mode is the same (i.e. not switched to EFI) and there is no known incompatibility between RAID controllers (this should not occur in most cases).

Comment: both of MBs have same intel chipset (Z77) asus has an additional raid controller AsMedia but i dont use that sata ports, i will use intel z77 ports so i wanna believe hdds will work on new mb

Comment: Being the same controller practically guarantees correct detection.

Comment: iam not sure if chipsets same, raid controllers are same. But i think it must be same musnt it ?

Comment: It's the controller that matters.

Answer (score 0):

> will my RAID array work on the new mainboard without any formatting?

It depends on how the RAID was setup and on the motherboards.
In your case I am assuming that you had used Intel's fake RAID (IRST) and both the motherboards have the same technology. So yes, in this case it should just work.

This is not always the case. E.g. if you had an old hardware RAID card, then the information on how the RAID array was build might be on that card.

For non-ancient RAID cards it is usually stored on the disk in some format which may or not be compatible with other cards.

But given that  motherboards are similar, same chipset is present and no mention of any HW RAID: Yes, this will most likely work.

> (I have some important files on my raid disks.)

Two more things:

1. "Generic RAID is not backup comment"<sup>tm</sup>.
   A lightning strike will fry the whole computer. A fire will cause you to loose everything. Do not assume that RAID means backup.
2. This is especially true for RAID 0. RAID0 is is not RAID in the traditional sense. **It has no redundancy at all.** It has increased risk of data loss. Use RAID0 only for **unimportant files** where speed is more important than reliability.
   E.g. for /tmp, scratch files, tmp database stuff, games which you can download again via steam/gog/.... Saved games file which are also saved in the cloud, ....
   DO not use RAID0 for important files without very good backups.

(Not trying to rub anything in here. Saying 'you should have had backups' is not going to help you. But explaining why might help other readers.)